# Regex problem with specific string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have problem with regex in python. I have the string:

`'Aaa Bbb', 'AaaBbbCcc' ,'OneTwost.Three'`

And I wanna get:

```
`'Aaa Bbb', 'Aaa Bbb Ccc'` 
and 'One Two st.Three' or 'One Two st. Three'
```

Generally, I need to insert space before every capital letter (if before capital letter is another sign than space) and if in string exist . (dot) than insert space 2 position back.

I'm very beginner at re library. I try do this based on a few topics in stack about regex, but I don't figure out this. Anyone have idea how do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])|(.{2}\.)
```

Which needs to be replaced with a function, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XIxurn/1/).

---

In `Python`  this could be

```
import re

data = """
Aaa Bbb
AaaBbbCcc
OneTwost.Three
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])|(.{2}\.)')

def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return " {} ".format(match.group(1))
    return r' '

data = rx.sub(replacer, data)
print(data)
```

Which yields

```
Aaa Bbb
Aaa Bbb Ccc
One Two st. Three
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said you want and the fact that you said, "I have the string":

> I have the string
>
> 'Aaa Bbb', 'AaaBbbCcc' ,'OneTwost.Three'

These should do it.

**Input:**

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """'Aaa Bbb', 'AaaBbbCcc' ,'OneTwost.Three'"""
```

**Output:**

```
>>> re.sub(r'((?<![\',\s])[A-Z]+|[\S]{2}\.)', r' \1', string)
"'Aaa Bbb', 'Aaa Bbb Ccc' ,'One Two st. Three'"
```

.

**Edit**

**Input (Acting on `string` and new variable `string_1` which removes the `'`'s)**

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """'Aaa Bbb', 'AaaBbbCcc' ,'OneTwost.Three'"""
>>> string_1 = """Aaa Bbb, AaaBbbCcc ,OneTwost.Three"""
```

**Output**

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?<!,)(?<!\s)(?<!\')([A-Z]+|[\S]{2}\.)', r' \1', string)
"'Aaa Bbb', 'Aaa Bbb Ccc' ,'One Two st. Three'"


>>> re.sub(r'(?:(?<!^)(?<!,)(?<!\s)(?<!\'))([A-Z]+|[\S]{2}\.)', r' \1', 
string)
"'Aaa Bbb', 'Aaa Bbb Ccc' ,'One Two st. Three'"


>>> re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?<!,)(?<!\s)(?<!\')([A-Z]+|[\S]{2}\.)', r' \1', string_1)
'Aaa Bbb, Aaa Bbb Ccc ,One Two st. Three'


>>> re.sub(r'(?:(?<!^)(?<!,)(?<!\s)(?<!\'))([A-Z]+|[\S]{2}\.)', r' \1', string_1)
'Aaa Bbb, Aaa Bbb Ccc ,One Two st. Three'
```

.

**Explanation of the First:**

- Made it a string as your quote suggested
- Using **re.sub** in this situation with the raw_string (r) option to allow for printing of dynamic/changing/variable capturing functionality and will return an edited string
- With the first `"("` I'm setting it up to capture everything in the subsequent query
- With `"(?<![\',\s])"`  I'm saying make sure that what follows which I am trying to capture is not preceded by a " ' " or  "whitespace"
- With `"[A-Z]+"` positioned where it is, I am saying capture any group of capital letters (**BUT NOTE: This will also match ABC, SDZ, FFRD, ZXF, etc. but will not capture any lowercase letters or other symbols**)
- With `"|"` I'm telling the re engine, "OR" capture this next query
- And with `"[\S]{2}\."` I'm saying capture if you find any 2 "non-whitespace characters" followed by a "."
- The final `")"` ends the capture group directive
- .
- With the second argument "r' \1'" I'm saying print the first group you capture (in this case I only have 1 capture group anyway) and place a single space in front of it

**Edit: Slight Explanation of the Following 2 which can act on string_1**

- I swear, `re.sub`'s behavior with lookarounds is just wonky. Given your comment below. Through each of the `(?<!YOUR_IGNORED_CHARACTER)`, I'm telling re.sub to essentially not capture if the capital letters are preceded by the designated character. `(?<!^)`, however, means do not capture if the capture group occurs at the beginning of the line.
- Note also, in the string for this example I've removed the `'` from the one you had given.

Comment: Thanks for help. It's magic for me. Are you have idea how consider specific letters, like polish words : 'ŚĆŻŹĄĘŁÓŃ' ? And is possible it's not insert space before first word in string? Situation like this: string = 'BbbŚaast.Ttt' ,result = 'Bbb Śaa st.Ttt' or 'Bbb Śaa st. Ttt' ?

Comment: With regards to Polish words, I'm not sure how to do it, honestly. Regarding your second question, I'm not sure what you mean, but I will post another comment to see if that can help

Comment: I tried it out, but the Polish letters make the regex break. Sorry about that man.

Comment: I mean now your regex insert space before every capital letter (include first word) and 2 char's before dot. I need solution which skip first word and after insert space before every capital letter (like your code) and capital polish letter ("ŚĆŻŹĄĘŁÓŃ") and 2 char's before dot sign (".").